# Is anyone aware of any recent neologisms to supercede "spinster" or "old maid" that have arisen?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, neologisms

I'm interested to see if, in fact, there are **any** new words in use from around the English-speaking world to replace the odious terms 'Spinster' and 'Old Maid'. I'm not referring to the term "unmarried woman" (which frequently has the age of the woman in question attached as an apparent matter of course).

I find it very curious that there is still such a stigma attached to a woman (in particular) choosing to remain unmarried! There are many people who just don't want to accrue a piece of paper and/or a partner who, statistically, at any rate, they are likely to end up having to go through the stress of divorcing at some point.

I live in a largely Agnostic country - so it's doubly strange to me.
I feel that there should be a "positive" term for those who wish to live by themselves the majority of the time. At any rate, a word which celebrates individualistic, non-promiscuous types of either/any(?) gender who *sometimes* co-habits with a boyfriend/girlfriend/Lover is sadly lacking I believe! Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I hear your desire and yes,  the situation does deserve  a word. For men, bachelor, or a 'confirmed bachelor',  doesn't carry the pejorative meaning although some might argue it suggests promiscuity.  I'm not so sure that the word itself suggests promiscuity or if people jump to the conclusion.

Comment: Short of an generally accepted term,  you might describe such a woman or man as an "independent spirit"  ,  or maybe "person who enjoys their social freedom" or ?  "usually unentangled? " ; )  I'll keep brainstorming

Comment: There's "bachelorette".  On the other hand, I don't think people use "bachelor" that much any more either. I think we just say a person is "single". The few times I've heard "He's a confirmed bachelor", it has been used to imply that the man in question is homosexual. As in this cartoon from *The New Yorker* back before same-sex marriage was legalized by the US Supreme Court: http://www.condenaststore.com/-sp/Technically-my-bachelorhood-isn-t-so-much-confirmed-as-it-is-legislated-New-Yorker-Cartoon-Prints_i8545336_.htm

Comment: You may refer to them as independent women by choice

Comment: The problem is, *any* new coinage will seem fresh for a while, but will then undergo the relentless chain of euphemization. Recall that "toilet" used to refer to the act of dressing oneself, not something one defecates into.

Comment: Considering our willingness to refer to any such middleaged-or-above woman with one or more cats as a "cat lady", we really are in want of some better terms.

Comment: I haven’t detected any stigma associated with women wishing to remain unmarried in many many years and that’s why there are no new words to replace spinster.

Comment: I would say *never married* as it has no value judgements.  I doubt any not-pejorative neologism will conjoin "old" with "never married" as merely deciding what the threshold for "old" is will impart judging someone has missed their typical marrying window.

Comment: Robusto, that's an exciting point.

Comment: "Never married" should have no pejorative implications though I'm far from convinced that that's the case ;-)

Comment: I meant to say "excellent" rather than "exciting". I shall never again use this site on my mobile phone... A whole year to discover my error! That's so deeply mortifying.

Comment: Also: Jim, you clearly haven't met my rural, Catholic step-relatives!

Answer (score 5):

**single**

> [a person that is] Unmarried or not involved in a stable sexual relationship

([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/single))

Comment: Simplest is often best, as it is here.  +1

Comment: I agree that simplest is generally best - however it would be nice if there were an edgy neologism for spinster. I live in Australia and have an extended Catholic step-family, most of whom live in the country! Every time I have to catch up with them I'm forced to endure relentless questions in the vein of "So, any new fellas in your life that I should know about?" and looks ranging from pity to what I'm fairly sure are

Comment: Phil Sweet - I doubt I could agree more!

Comment: Jim, that could actually be  (and I'm just guessing here) because you're a man...